# Generic type that accepts types that are implementing Comparable by inheriting it

Tags: java, generics

How to make `DataStructure` to accept type `B` without using raw types?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataStructure<A> bo = new DataStructure<>();

        //This doesn't compile because of T extends Comparable<T> 
        DataStructure<B> bst = new DataStructure<>();
    }
}

class DataStructure<T extends Comparable<T>> {
}

abstract class A implements Comparable<A> {
}

abstract class B extends A /*implements Comparable<B> - illegal*/ {
}
```

I can change `DataStructure` signature to: `class DataStructure<T extends Comparable>` but then I get warning about raw type. I can't do `class DataStructure<T extends Comparable<? extends T>>` because when `T == B` the `? extends T` is obviously false.

Comment: B can't implement `Comparable<B>`: it already implements `Comparable<A>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataStructure<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```